# MOVS with LSL Carry Flag

Tags: arm

I'm learning The Arm System Developers Guide and I am wondering about one of the examples in the book:

```
cpsr = nzcvqiFt_USER   // capital indicates flag is set
r0 = 0x00000000
r1 = 0x80000004

MOVS r0, r1, LSL #1

cpsr = nzCvqiFt_USER   // capital indicates flag is set
r0 = 0x00000008
r1 = 0x80000004
```

I understand that the 8 is carried over and the C flag is set due to this carry based on the logical shift left.  Why is the 4 in r1 not shifted as well?  Is the MOVS operation only moving the carried 8?

Comment: The third bit should be 2^2=4 and the fourth 2^3=8. It seems to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your result ends up in r0.

So, what happens is:

```
carry = r1[31] = 1
r0    = r1 << 1
```

Thats why r0 becomes `0x00000008` because the MSB of r1 got shifted out to the carry and the third bit (2^3=4) got shifted to the fourth bit (2^4=8).